# magento menu link need php code

Tags: magento

I had to create a static menu link in menu.html. which is linked to a static pages content (with # tag

Shop

).
when I click on that menu, it goes to that content. (URL changes to--www.domain.com/#mc) then, when I click on another menu, it goes to that. but, when I again 
want to go back to that (# tagged) menu, it doesnt go (URL changes to--www.domain.com/contacts#sc).

I think, the static menu link should be in php code. but, I cant write 
the code. any one please will me writing the code?

Answer (score 2):

You this code for static URL

```
$this->getUrl('', array(''_fragment=>'sg'));
```

You can detail explanation [**here**](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters)

Answer (score 0):

## tag in the url will always try to look for id in your current html page.

Try with giving the full url for your static menu link where html contains an element with id "mc"